# Binary Classification using TDA

Tags: machine-learning, data-analysis

Suppose I have a dataset with some attributes, if the values of attributes is the same for two case but the label is different, how can topological data analysis can be helpful to carry out such kind of dataset.

Comment: are all the attributes the same?

Comment: yes. Lets say like you have attributes like age, weight, height etc all the values are same and label is one is male and other one is female.

Comment: Don't know TDA but the way most ML methods deal with contradictions/noise in the data is to minimize the error. Practically it means that if considering this instance as label X causes less errors than as label Y, then it chooses the former.